# How can I render username in the templates?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-users

I created an app where a user can register and login and post a video, How can I render username in the post. I want to pass a username in each and every post user did. like social networking

this is my model

```
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
    title = CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is my template home templates:

```
    <div class="container">
    {% for post in posting %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                    <video
                    id="my-video"
                    class="video-js" 
                    controls
                    width="640"
                    height="264"
                    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
                    data-setup="{}"
                    type="video/mp4"
                    >
                    <source src="{{post.file.url}}">
                </video>
            <div class="card-body">
                <small>{{post.date_added}}</small>
                <br>
               <small>{{post.title}}</small>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

this is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Post

def dashboard(request):
    posting = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'posting': posting})
```

this is my login views:

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credential') 
        return redirect('login')
else:        
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

this is my register views:

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email Already taking')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                return redirect('register')
           else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save();
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

I want pass a username in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the username of the user with `post.user.username`, so for example:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <small>{{post.date_added}} by {{ post.user.username }}</small>
    <br>
   <small>{{post.title}}</small>
</div>
```

in the view you can boost performance by selecting the relevant users with the `Post` in a single query:

```
def dashboard(request):
    posting = Post.objects.select_related('user')
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'posting': posting})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: What are the benefits of using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL sir ?

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: if you later change the user model with another one, the `ForeignKey`s will point to the new user model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: So now I should add this in to my user field user = models.ForeignKey( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,) ?

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: yes, normally that will not change anything since the default user model is `auth.User`.

Comment: Does that make my application unsafe for the user ? I mean does that can effect user when they are using the app. Can I leave it as I am a beginner in Django ? What should happen if I change it to OneToOneField ? Instead of ForeignKey ?

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: you can keep it, is is simply not a good practice. Changing it to a `OneToOneField` makes no sense, since that would mean a user can only post *at most one* `Post`.

Comment: No, a user can post at many times he want. I mean he can add a new post as many as he want to.

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: exactly so changing it to a `OneToOneField` is non-sensical here.

Comment: Okay sir. So now I can leave it as ForeignKey ?

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: yes.